# If $f$ is differentiable on ℝ and $f’$ is strictly increasing, show that $f’$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

If f is differentiable on ℝ and $f’$ is strictly increasing, show that $f’$ is continuous.
**Hint:** Prove that if a function $g$ is strictly increasing, then either $\sup_{x<a} g(x) < \inf_{x>a} g(x)$ or g is continuous at $a \in ℝ$.

Comment: Please tell us where you are stuck

Comment: @TheDeadLegend I have a hard time comprehending  $\sup_{x<a} g(x) < \inf_{x>a}g(x)$

Comment: Note that derivatives satisfy intermediate value property. And if a function is monotone and satisfies ivp then it is continuous.

Comment: @TheDeadLegend I'm thinking about showing that f' being discontinuous at x = a contradicts the limit definition of f'(a)